# Python Error: the following arguments are required: -p/--shape-predictor

Tags: python, opencv

I'm new to work with python and i want to run this code , but get this error.
code:

```
# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-p", "--shape-predictor", required=True, help="path to facial landmark predictor")
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video", type=str, default="", help="path to input video file")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xrdoj.jpg)

usage:

```
detect_blinks.py [-h] -p SHAPE_PREDICTOR
```

Error I'm Getting is:

```
the following arguments are required: -p/--shape-predictor
```

Comment: The source code defines a function that will execute in the command line. The "[-h]" part in the usage is a placeholder from python kindly saying you can get help by writing `detect_blinks.py -h`. What happens when you do `detect_blinks.py -p SHAPE PREDICTOR` ?

Answer (score 0):

As the usage says, You need pass the necessary parameter `-p/--shape-predictor`.

you can just run this scripts as follows:

```sh
python detect_blinks.py -p my/path/to/predictor
```